# Best way to organize and develope a CLI Python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I am working on a cli application in someways similar to [aws-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli).

I started my project with all my code in one big python file. it seems a bit disorganize so I broke up the code into a folder `somethingcli` similar to `awscli`.

I also made a directory `bin/` with similar code that you find in `aws-cli`.

But now I am unable to run it.

I have the similar error when I try to run `aws-cli`.

So I would do: `python3 ./bin/aws`

Then get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/Other/aws-cli/./bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli'
```

I understand the error... But how is one supposed to run the code when you are developing? Are you supposed to run `./setup.py` each time? Confusing.

So I run the install and then go to wherever it installed everything and then work on the code there and copy it back in the directory to then push it to my repo?

Also when I run the unit-tests for `aws-cli` I get a bunch of errors.

I am still new to Python so this might be a very stupid question. I am just trying to do things the right way.

Python version: Python 3.9.13

Comment: How are you installing the `awscli module`, and how are you running the code?  Often in cases like these, your problem is that you have multiple versions of Python on your machine, and you are installing the `awscli` module into one version of Python and running your code from another. - You should never have to run `./setup.py` more than once for any one version/installation of Python.

Comment: I haven't installed anything yet. But the way I run it is: `python3 ./bin/aws`. I also tried: `python3 ./awscli` but I get another error.